# Synchronization of clocks

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

I have read the book 
"Introduction to special relativity " by Robert Resnick
In the book I have found that
"*If the distance between the clocks is L, one observer will see the other clock lag his by 2L/c when other observer claims that they are synchronous*" in the section 2.1(The Relativity of Simultaneity)
How does this result come??
I did not understand..!!

Comment: Section 2.1 of Resnick does not contain what you say it contains. Please be specific with your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a relativistic effect. This is simply a consequence of information delay due to the speed of light being finite. $L/c$ is the time it takes for light to travel the distance $L$. Hence the information transmitted by light over the distance $L$ will be delayed by $L/c$. If the two clocks were exactly synchronized (in the stationary reference frame), both observers would see the other clock lagging by $L/c$. If one observer sees the two clocks as synchronous, that means her/his clock is actually lagging by $L/c$, which means the other observer would see it as lagging by $2L/c$.